# Displaying 2 images vertically

Tags: android

I'm trying to display 2 images in the same activity, one on top of the other using a fake view. And I want the 2 images to stretch their width to cover the screen width and stretch their height so that each one covers half of the screen. How to do it in XML only ?

Comment: Next time, try and show people what you have done so far so they know little effort has been taken otherwise people will down vote your question which isn't nice.

Answer (score 1):

The layout will be like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Create a LinearLayout with Vertical orientation
- Add 2 ImageViews or ImageButtons, one on top and the other at the bottom
- set there Layout weight to be equal
- set each ImageView layout width to match_Parent
- set the image to FITXY for the ImageViews

Comment: Set set each ImageView layout height to **0dp**, in order for weights to work.